# pyinstaller & django OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, pyinstaller

I am trying to compile a django web application using pyinstaller.
I used following command:

```
 /usr/local/python2.7/bin/pyinstaller --name=zhaobiao ./zbproject/manage.py
```

When I executed the compiled exe it gave me following error:

```
    [root@smon zhaobiao]# ./dist/zhaobiao/zhaobiao runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f5220297410>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
  File "site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
  File "site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 163, in check_migrations
  File "site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
  File "site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
  File "site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 170, in build_graph
  File "site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 98, in load_disk
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/Downloads/dist/zhaobiao/zbapp/migrations'
```

Then I find out migrations directory at following position:

```
[root@smon zhaobiao]# find . -iname 'migrations'
./django/contrib/admin/migrations
./django/contrib/auth/migrations
./django/contrib/sessions/migrations
./django/contrib/sites/migrations
./django/contrib/redirects/migrations
./django/contrib/contenttypes/migrations
./django/contrib/flatpages/migrations
./django/conf/app_template/migrations
```

So the path mismatch ,how should i do?

Comment: Do you need to use pyinstaller? I would suggest using pip and virtualenv

Comment: i just want to make  an  executable Windows programs. the virtualenv  can   achieve? @jonprasetyo

Answer (score 0):

I have copy the directory /root/Downloads/zbproject/zbapp  to /root/Downloads/dist/zhaobiao/

now it works.

```
[root@smon test]# ./dist/zhaobiao/zhaobiao runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 30, 2016 - 03:04:49
Django version 1.9.5, using settings 'zhaobiao.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```